# Should we allow name-and-shame answers?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34895/10211

Like @MDMoore313 mentioned in the comments, the person being mentioned in the answer probably isn't behind the attacks.

I feel that we should not allow naming any particular person in this type of questions as it has the potential to ruin the reputation of an innocent person. Any questions/answers mentioning a person in such a context should be flagged and cleaned up by a mod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we are at the reddit level here (where the naming of an alleged Boston bomber apparently led to an innocent person committing suicide) as we are generally a community that should be able to look at the information from the perspective of a security professional.

That said, in that specific example I think it would be more useful to incorporate the comment into the answer, and say that a lot of the traffic is coming from that domain, rather than naming the individual as the one responsible. Feel free to edit.